# create environment module to work with opencv-python on hpc nodes

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, hpc, torque, environment-modules

I have a task to train neural networks using tensorflow and opencv-python on HPC nodes via Torque.

I have made privatemodule with python virtualenv and installed tensorflow and  opencv-python modules in it.

In the node I can load my python module. 
But when I try to run training script I get following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensornetwork/train_user_ind_single_subj2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from reader_user_ind_single_subj import MyData
  File "/home/trig/tensornetwork/reader_user_ind_single_subj.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/trig/privatemodules/venv_python275/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The training script can run on head node, but cant on compute node.

Can you suggest how to modify my module or add a new module to make training run on compute node using Torque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python module uses a system library (namely `libSM.so.6` : library support for the freedesktop.org version of X) that is present on the head node, but not on the compute nodes (which is not very surprising)

You can either:

- ask the administrators to have that library installed systemwide on the compute nodes through the package manager ;
- or locate the file on the head node (probably in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` or siblings), and copy it in `/home/trig/privatemodules/venv_python275/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/`, where Python should find it. If Python still does not find it, run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/trig/privatemodules/venv_python275/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/` in your Torque script after you load the module.
- or you can search for the source for `libSM` and compile it in your home directory